# Tell apollo-client what gets returned from X query with Y argiments?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a list of `Item`s of whatever type. I can query all of them with `query items` or one with `query item(id)`.

I realize apollo can't know what will be returned. It knows the type, but it doesn't know the exact data. Maybe there is a way not to make additional request? Map one query onto another?

Pseudo-code:

```
// somewhere in Menu.tsx (renders first)
let items = useQuery(GET_ITEMS);
return items.map(item => <MenuItemRepresenation item={item} />);

// meanwhile in apollo cache (de-normalized for readability):
{ ROOT_QUERY: {
    items: [  // query name per schema
      { id: 1, data: {...}, __typename: "Item" },
      { id: 2, data: {...}, __typename: "Item" },
      { id: 3, data: {...}, __typename: "Item" },
    ]
  }
} 

// somewhere in MainView.tsx (renders afterwards)
let neededId = getNeededId();  // 2
let item = useQuery(GET_ITEM, { variables: { id: neededId } } );
return <MainViewRepresentation item={item} />;
```

Code like this will do two fetches. Even though the data is already in the cache. But it seems apollo thinks on query level. I would like a way to explain to it: *"If I make `item` query, you need to look over here at `items` query you did before. If it has no item with that id go ahead and make the request."*

Something akin to this can be done by querying `items` in `MainView.tsx` and combing through the results. It might work for pseudo-code, but in a real app it's not that simple: cache might be empty in some cases. Or not sufficient to satisfy required fields. Which means we have to load all items when we need just one.

Upon further research `Apollo Link` looks promising. It might be possible to intercept outgoing queries. Will investigate tomorrow.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. GraphQL is a strongly typed language. Apollo Client will "know" what an item is based on the `__typename` returned by the server. Maybe you can edit your question to better explain what you're asking, ideally including some snippets of code or pseudocode to illustrate your point.

Comment: @DanielRearden hi, expanded as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind apollo link. What I was looking for is called `cacheRedirects`.
It's an option for `ApolloClient` or `Cache` constructor.

```
cacheRedirects: {
  Query: {
    node: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) => {
      const cacheKey = getCacheKey({
        __typename: "Item",
        id: args.id,
      });

      return cacheKey;
    },
  },
},
```

I'd link to documentation but it's never stable. I've seen too many dead links from questions such as this.